error: redefinition of _Is_memfunptr when trying to compile with icx
I'm new to SYCL. And I'm having some trouble compiling an almost empty program, and I really don't understand how to fix the redefinition of type_traits.
I've tried all the compilation command options (and haven't forgotten about setvars.bat, OS Windows):
icx-cl -fsycl main_ecg.cpp
icx -fsycl main_ecg.cpp
icpx -fsycl main_ecg.cpp
dpcpp -fsycl main_ecg.cpp

Also without -fsycl flag
main_ecg.cpp
#include <sycl/sycl.hpp>

int main() {
    return 0;
}

And the result is
FAILED: EvilCG/CMakeFiles/EvilCG.dir/src/main_ecg.cpp.obj
C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\latest\bin\icx.exe  /nologo /TP  -IC:\Users\teoru\MAIN_FOLDER\.MAIN\EvilCG\EvilCG\.\inc -external:IC:\Users\teoru\MAIN_FOLDER\.INCLUDES\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include -external:W0 /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /EHsc /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG -MD -fsycl -QMD -QMT EvilCG\CMakeFiles\EvilCG.dir\src\main_ecg.cpp.obj -QMF EvilCG\CMakeFiles\EvilCG.dir\src\main_ecg.cpp.obj.d /FoEvilCG\CMakeFiles\EvilCG.dir\src\main_ecg.cpp.obj /FdEvilCG\CMakeFiles\EvilCG.dir\EvilCG.pdb -c C:\Users\teoru\MAIN_FOLDER\.MAIN\EvilCG\EvilCG\src\main_ecg.cpp
In file included from C:\Users\teoru\MAIN_FOLDER\.MAIN\EvilCG\EvilCG\src\main_ecg.cpp:2:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\iostream:10:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\istream:10:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\ostream:10:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\ios:10:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\xlocnum:14:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\iterator:11:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\xutility:11:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\__msvc_iter_core.hpp:10:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\utility:11:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\type_traits(528,30): error: redefinition of '_Is_memfunptr<_Ret (_Arg0::*)(_Types...) __attribute__((fastcall))>'
  528 | _MEMBER_CALL_CV_REF_NOEXCEPT(_IS_MEMFUNPTR)
      | ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\type_traits(451,25): note: expanded from macro '_MEMBER_CALL_CV_REF_NOEXCEPT'
  451 |     _MEMBER_CALL_CV_REF(FUNC, )            \
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\type_traits(445,21): note: expanded from macro '_MEMBER_CALL_CV_REF'
  445 |     _MEMBER_CALL_CV(FUNC, , NOEXCEPT_OPT)       \


Well, that was my mistake. I use oneAPI command prompt for IA32 (Intel oneAPI command prompt for IA32 for Visual Studio 2022) instead 64 (Intel oneAPI command prompt for Intel 64 for Visual Studio 2022)
